# AJAX won't get PHP - echo

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So I'm trying to build a pretty simple website, to learn basic webdesign. It's just a random quote generator - you click on a button and it prints some famous quote. Anyway, I try to use ajax to get the quote, so I use this function:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","RandomQuote.php",true)
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

but no matter what I type into RandomQuote.php, even if it's something like :

```
<?php 
 echo 'Hello, world';
 ?>
```

nothing shows up in the quote "div', it just becomes blank. I really have no idea what's the problem here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: use Jquery and Ajax function to make asynchronous calls. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: That's because PHP has already rendered the page.  If you need to echo a response, put it in an iframe, innerHTML.  Use Javascript to print out the response.

Comment: Open your developer tools tab and watch for network traffic. Is it actually making the request?

Comment: Rarely will I suggest to just use jQuery for normal javascript functions, but ajax is one of those things that is a really big pain to do "manually", as it were... if you're trying to learn it, that's fine, or if you're trying to cut down the bulk of your page as much as possible, I get that, too... but otherwise, even if you only use it for ajax, then I'd still do it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure about much, but are you calling your function? You put your ajax inside  loadXMLDoc() , so you probably have to call it. Another way is to put your ajax into an addEventListener so when a user clicks on something, it'll execute. If that's not the problem, try making sure your element in your html page with the id of "quote" is spelled correctly. Sometimes the latter scenario is always the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.get( "RandomQuote.php", function( data ) {
      $( "#quote" ).html( data );
      console.log( "Load was performed." );
    });
```

Don't forget to include jQuery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my ajax function, try to use it:

```
/**
 * @function ajax               Send ajax-request with post
 * @param  {string}   xmlpage   Target url
 * @param  {string}   data      Post parameters (like param1=val1&param2=val2...)
 * @param  {Function} callback
 * @return {null}    
 */
function ajax(xmlpage, data, callback)
{ 
    var xmlh = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlh = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        try
        { 
            xmlh = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
        }
        catch(ex) 
        { 
            xmlh = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        }
    if(xmlh)
    {
        xmlh.open("post", xmlpage, true);
        xmlh.onreadystatechange = function(x) 
                            { 
                                if(xmlh.readyState==4 && typeof callback !== 'undefined') 
                                    callback(xmlh.responseText); 
                            }
        xmlh.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language","ru, en");
        xmlh.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlh.send(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following test files using your code from the question. It is working perfectly. Either you are missing something or its a browser issue. I tested on Mozilla. To be sure of browser independent code use jQuery for Ajax call

test.html

```
<html>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","RandomQuote.php",true)
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<div id="quote"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="loadXMLDoc()"/>
</html>
```

RandomQuote.php

```
<?php

echo 'hi';
```

Update: jQuery version

```
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    $.get( "RandomQuote.php", function( data ) {
      $( "#quote" ).html( data );
    });

}
</script>
<div id="quote"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="loadXMLDoc()"/>
</html>
```